# Read all email messages from a text file containing multiple email messages using python

Tags: python, email

I have a single txt file which contains multiple email messages. Attached a sample text file which contains multiple email (.eml format)

```
From details
Return-Path: <emailaddress>
Delivered-To: email@address.com
Received: details
Received-SPF: details
Authentication-Results: details
Received: details
ARC-Seal: details
ARC-Message-Signature: details
Received: details
From: details
To: details
Subject: details
Thread-Topic: details
Thread-Index: details
Date: details
Message-ID:details
Accept-Language: en-US
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
boundary="_004_DM5PR13MB138821372E6760B35B854B0CB74A0DM5PR13MB1388namp_"
MIME-Version: 1.0
details
--_004_DM5PR13MB138821372E6760B35B854B0CB74A0DM5PR13MB1388namp_
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
boundary="_000_DM5PR13MB138821372E6760B35B854B0CB74A0DM5PR13MB1388namp_"
--_000_DM5PR13MB138821372E6760B35B854B0CB74A0DM5PR13MB1388namp_
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
test with FA

--_000_DM5PR13MB138821372E6760B35B854B0CB74A0DM5PR13MB1388namp_
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html>
<head>
<body>
details
</body>
</html>

--_000_DM5PR13MB138821372E6760B35B854B0CB74A0DM5PR13MB1388namp_--

--_004_DM5PR13MB138821372E6760B35B854B0CB74A0DM5PR13MB1388namp_
Content-Type: details
Content-Description: details
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="p2_eml.eml"; size=37836;
creation-date="Tue, 04 Aug 2020 10:48:34 GMT";
modification-date="Tue, 04 Aug 2020 10:48:34 GMT"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
base64encoded data

--_004_DM5PR13MB138821372E6760B35B854B0CB74A0DM5PR13MB1388namp_--

From details <--- 2nd email starts --->
Return-Path: <emailaddress>
Delivered-To: email@address.com
Received: details
Received-SPF: details
Authentication-Results: details
Received: details
more details
```

Using email lib by python, it can grab only 1st email message, but does not process rest of email messages.
But this creates a single msg object that refers to 1st email message in the txt file.

Is there a way i can fetch all email messages from txt file and process one by one?
**msg = email.message_from_file(message)** this only fetches the 1st email message object. Does not fetch the next message obj.

Code tried:

````py
    msg = email.message_from_file(message)

    # Dump extra information To, From, Date, Subject header values.
    dump_extra_info(msg)

    decoded_content_list = []
    for part in msg.walk():
        charset = part.get_content_charset();
        if part.get_content_type() == "application/octet-stream":
            logger.info("found content disposition returning ...")
            continue
        decoded_data = part.get_payload(decode=True)
        if decoded_data and charset is not None:
            utf8decoded = decoded_data.decode(charset)
            decoded_content_list.append(utf8decoded)
    return ' '.join(decoded_content_list)```
    ```
````

Comment: Can you add the sample of txt file and more code which you used?

Comment: How are the messages separated in the file?

Comment: Please update your post with more code, so we can help you.

Comment: Added more code and sample txt file. The email message is in standard RFC2822 format https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email#Internet_Message_Format
Message is seperated by a blank line